# How can I recreate this well-lit, vibrant, hi-contrast lighting setup?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, lighting

[image]
*Above render by Peter Tarka*

So, in this scene, the lighting is bright, vibrant and yet not over-exposed, and no details are lost. Every time I try something like this, my scene ends up becoming overexposed or washed out. How can I achieve this level of detail and clarity?

Here is a quick sample of my scene—

[image: my scene]

Comment: I think it's both a question of material color and lighting, did you try a stronger light (sun)?

Comment: Yup. But then the shadows get sharp and angular, unlike the softer ones in the reference image.

Comment: you can use the blend value to make the shadows less sharp, are you working with cycles or eevee? maybe share your file (just leave one object, the plane and the lights)

Comment: Cycles. But I think the tutorial listed below seems to do the trick—I tried the same setup, and got me close to where I was trying to get at.

Comment: oh ok good so maybe give the trick you used to fix your scene

Comment: Sure—like I mentioned in the comment to the answer below, I merely followed the tutorial, and removed ambient occlusion from the scene. That was screwing up the shadow values, both the factor and the distance values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the concepts of three point lighting-

First is the **Key light**

- It usually is quite bright light, facing the subject at certain angle (Basically to lit the subject from one angle)

Second is **Fill light**

- To lite the subject from another side/Angle(To fill the Dark shadows created by the Key light).

Third **Rim Light**

- A VERY Bright light from the back of the subject to create an outline of Brightness on the subject also it helps to highlight the shape of the Subject .

Now you have a basic **3 Point Light** Setup.

Now you can use your Imagination and creativity to explore the lighting setup by changing the Intensity or Colors and the Size of the Lights also additionally, if you are trying to lit a subject/object and not a scene in particular; Then create a Backdrop or just a ground plane to have a nice bounced light on your subject. Also please consider the Size of your lights while lighting your scene as the Size of the light will affect the way the shadows are being cast and also it can change the look and mood of your subject or Scene."

Please, refer to [**this tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ1IE-CMik8). This can be a good help for you for lighting in blender.

Comment: Ok, let me go through this, thanks!

Comment: This did the trick. And also, I had ambient occlusion set to some random value, and that was spoiling the whole setup. Removed that, and followed the tut, and got me close. Thanks!

Comment: Its good to know it worked for you. Great!

Comment: hello, could you please quickly precise what trick/settings were used in this tutorial?

Comment: Three lights in the scene—one area light, as the key light, facing the subject, and another area light coming in from the side. Then a third light, a “rim” light from the back, to highlight the shape of the object better. This rim light needs to be the brightest in the scene by far. The other two you just play with values and see what works best.

Comment: And also please do use a backdrop(Depending on your scene), as it will give you a nice bounced light.

Comment: @HDFXVFX please help us with keeping useful answers in this site. A link is not really an answer, if the link goes down, then there is no answer anymore. Please outline the main concepts so that other users can learn.